# Failed to install quadprog on Linux Mint 20

Tags: python, linux, numpy, linux-mint, quadprog

has anyone installed this *quadprog* lib on **Python 3.8** and **Linux Mint 20**? I'm trying to install and the following error is appearing:

```
pip install quadprog
Collecting quadprog
  Using cached quadprog-0.1.8.tar.gz (269 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from quadprog) (0.29.21)
Building wheels for collected packages: quadprog
  Building wheel for quadprog (setup.py) ... [?25lerror
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/hugosouza/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-8o_4txn2/quadprog_089e8c8a9afa4563849d61ace43b3f03/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-8o_4txn2/quadprog_089e8c8a9afa4563849d61ace43b3f03/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-r3kgatse
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-8o_4txn2/quadprog_089e8c8a9afa4563849d61ace43b3f03/
  Complete output (12 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  skipping 'quadprog/quadprog.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  building 'quadprog' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/quadprog
  gcc -pthread -B /home/hugosouza/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Iquadprog -I/home/hugosouza/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c quadprog/quadprog.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/quadprog/quadprog.o
  gcc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1plus’: execvp: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for quadprog
nning setup.py clean for quadprog
Failed to build quadprog
^C
ERROR: Operation cancelled by user
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `g++` or `build-essential` (which will install g++)

```
apt-get install g++
```

Comment: It Works! Thanks!